# Android Studio Rendering Problems with GridViewPager (Android Wear)

Tags: android, layout, nullpointerexception, android-studio, wear-os

Everytime I use a android.support.wearable.view.GridViewPager in a layout, I get this error in the editor.

[image: GridViewPager NullPointerException]

```
Rendering Problems
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at android.support.wearable.view.GridViewPager.recomputeScrollPosition(GridViewPager.java:1236)
  at android.support.wearable.view.GridViewPager.onSizeChanged(GridViewPager.java:1190)
  at android.view.View.sizeChange(View.java:15083)
  at android.view.View.setFrame(View.java:15056)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14964)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14968)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14968)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
```

Do somebody know how to resolve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of `com.google.android.support:wearable` are you using? Because this looks like it might be a (fixed) bug in `GridViewPager`.

If you compare the relevant lines between the 1.0.0 and 1.1.0 versions of the class, you can see that there is a missing null check that was changed later. In version 1.0.0:

```
ItemInfo ii = infoForPosition(this.mCurItem);
int targetX = ii != null ? computePageLeft(ii.positionX) - getPaddingLeft() : 0;
int targetY = ii != null ? computePageTop(ii.positionY) - getPaddingTop() : 0;

// NPE in following line (1236), only possible if ii == null.
if ((targetX != getScrollX(ii.positionY)) || (targetY != getScrollY()))
{
   ...
```

while version 1.1.0 is:

```
ItemInfo ii = infoForPosition(this.mCurItem);
if (ii != null) // <- check is moved here.
{
    int targetX = computePageLeft(ii.positionX) - getPaddingLeft();
    int targetY = computePageTop(ii.positionY) - getPaddingTop();
    if ((targetX != getRowScrollX(ii.positionY)) || (targetY != getScrollY()))
    {
        ...
```

I would try updating and rebuilding.